# Hide extensions of the pages when hosted

Tags: hosting, web-hosting

All,

I had a question on hosting.I have Pages that are written in php  or JSP and is hosted on a server .And if a user enter say  http://x.com in the browser, the main.php or main.asp page will be displayed.My question is there a way to hide the extensions..

Thanks...........

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1 mod_rewrite / ISAPI filter to rewrite**

For mod_rewrite on Apache, it is as simple as adding a .htaccess file to the root directory of your website with the following content...

The following rule will direct all URIs in this format:

```
http://yoursite.com/Content/Page/
```

to

```
http://yoursite.com/Page.php
```

IE the last bit of the URI gets transformed into a PHP file of the same name.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^Content/([^/\.]+)/?$ $1.php [L,NC,QSA]
```

**Option 2 directory structure**

This is where you have a folder structure to represent your website and each folder has an index.php file. For example,

```
http://yoursite.com/Contact-Us/index.php
```

In this example, visiting

```
http://yoursite.com/Contact-Us/
```

gives you the extensionless URI that you are after as the index.php page is shown by default.

I only mention this as it is a solution for a situation where you on shared Windows hosting and cannot add an ISAPI filter.

Answer (score 1):

You want [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) or one of its [IIS equivalents](http://www.google.com/search?q=iis+rewrite).

Answer (score 0):

Provided you are using an apache server, you can do this with url rewriting in .htaccess. See http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/02/hide-php-url-rewriting-htaccess.html